# display wordpress post meta in editor after save

Tags: php, wordpress, post, meta

I am trying to write a small plugin in wordpress, I have a small meta box with text input and a radio button in which user needs to add information, and I want that the imformation that is saved in the post meta box will be displayed after save (in the current state the input text resets to the default plaholder after save).

this is the relevant code:

```
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'asset_price' );
function asset_price() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'asset_price',
        __( 'asset price', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'asset_price_box_content',
        'asset',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}

function asset_price_box_content( $post ) {
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'asset_price_box_content_nonce' );
  echo '<label for="asset_price"></label>
        <input type="text" id="asset_price" name="asset_price" placeholder="insert price" />
        <input type="radio" name="currency" value="percent" checked="checked">%
        <input type="radio" name="currency" value="Dollar">$';
    }

add_action( 'save_post', 'asset_price_box_save' );
function asset_price_box_save( $post_id ) {

  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
  return $post_id;

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['asset_price_box_content_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
  return $post_id;

  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id; 
  } else {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;
  }
  $old = get_post_meta($post_id, "asset_price", true);
$new = $_POST["asset_price"];
if ($new && $new != $old) {
  $product_price = $_POST['asset_price'];
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'asset_price', $product_price );
}  elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
delete_post_meta($post_id, "asset_price", $old);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the meta box value using `get_post_meta()` function and display it in the textbox

```
function asset_price_box_content( $post ) {
    $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, "asset_price", true);
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'asset_price_box_content_nonce' );
    echo '<label for="asset_price"></label>
        <input type="text" id="asset_price" name="asset_price" placeholder="insert price" value="'.$price.'" />
        <input type="radio" name="currency" value="percent" checked="checked">%
        <input type="radio" name="currency" value="Dollar">$';
    }
```

Comment: Excellent thanks! this did the job, but for some reason it only saves the value of the text input field, but not the radio button selection (It also won't display when I show the meta box content in the single.php) any idea?

Comment: because you only updating the textbox value, save radio button value same as what we did for textbox